# Getting an error with npm start in project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to start a project after installing npm modules.

When I type `npm start` I get:

```
There is an error in your gulpfile: 
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tkhusid/WebstormProjects/Ionic-`enter code here`radar/ionic-radar/config/gulp/index.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

In addition I get another errors next to this error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev:stub"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! techradar-ionic@0.2.0 dev:stub: `ionic serve --environment local`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the techradar-ionic@0.2.0 dev:stub script 'ionic serve --environment local'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the techradar-ionic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic serve --environment local
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs techradar-ionic
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls techradar-ionic
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/tkhusid/WebstormProjects/Ionic-radar/ionic-radar/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! techradar-ionic@0.2.0 dev: `npm run dev:stub`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the techradar-ionic@0.2.0 dev script 'npm run dev:stub'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the techradar-ionic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run dev:stub
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs techradar-ionic
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls techradar-ionic
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/tkhusid/WebstormProjects/Ionic-radar/ionic-radar/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! techradar-ionic@0.2.0 start: `npm run dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the techradar-ionic@0.2.0 start script 'npm run dev'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the techradar-ionic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs techradar-ionic
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls techradar-ionic
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have started with a cloning of the project.
The project has been clonned successfully.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: try with nodejs v6 instead of v4; node v6 has better support for ecmascript 6 and the error seems to be related to this (code being written in es6)

Comment: Thanks. Will try now

Comment: Doesn't help :(

Comment: Oh, You was right mate! It works! I have downloaded node6. Then I have updated some npm libraries and it get worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok I posted an answer so that you can mark the question as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message

> Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

it seems the issue comes from the fact that the code is written with EcmaScript 6, and you use nodejs v4 which does not yet fully support ES6. Try upgrading to nodejs v6 which has better ES6 support, and perhaps update some npm dependencies.

> npm ERR! node v4.6.0